# Import .csv to SQL Developer automatically and not manually

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am creating a Procedure that allows me to import a csv on SQL Developer (Oracle). Is there a way to do this by spooling on terminal? I am not interested in solutions with UTF File and SQL Loader.

Comment: No, actually there isn't anyway because SQL developer just use sql loader to import csv. beyond Java interface. Then only method to import from terminal is to create a Sql Loader file and schedule it.

Comment: Would you explain me how to do it? As a terminal I don't have great experiences ..

Comment: To invoke sqlloader can you use --> sqlldr USER_DB/PASSWORD control=./FILESQLLOADER.ctl direct=false where FILESQLLOADER.ctl contains table, fields and file to import. For file example sqlloader can you open this link https://ocptechnology.com/how-to-load-data-from-csv-file-into-oracle-using-sql-loader/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question title and and then question contents conflict each other somewhat.

If you're looking for tooling support to automatically import CSV, then the answer is 'yes.'

'Spooling on the terminal' - you can use Oracle SQLcl which is our command line version of SQL Developer.

It has a 'LOAD' command which takes CSV and puts it to a table, automatically.

```
SQL> SET sqlformat csv
SQL> cd /Users/thatjeffsmith
SQL> spool objects.csv
SQL> SELECT * FROM all_objects fetch FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY;
"OWNER","OBJECT_NAME","SUBOBJECT_NAME","OBJECT_ID","DATA_OBJECT_ID","OBJECT_TYPE","CREATED","LAST_DDL_TIME","TIMESTAMP","STATUS","TEMPORARY","GENERATED","SECONDARY","NAMESPACE","EDITION_NAME","SHARING","EDITIONABLE","ORACLE_MAINTAINED","APPLICATION","DEFAULT_COLLATION","DUPLICATED","SHARDED","CREATED_APPID","CREATED_VSNID","MODIFIED_APPID","MODIFIED_VSNID"
"SYS","I_FILE#_BLOCK#","",9,9,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_OBJ3","",38,38,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_TS1","",45,45,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_CON1","",51,51,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","IND$","",19,2,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,21-NOV-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","CDEF$","",31,29,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","C_TS#","",6,6,"CLUSTER",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",5,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_CCOL2","",58,58,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_PROXY_DATA$","",24,24,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_CDEF4","",56,56,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_TAB1","",33,33,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","CLU$","",5,2,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_PROXY_ROLE_DATA$_1","",26,26,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_OBJ1","",36,36,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","UNDO$","",15,15,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_UNDO2","",35,35,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_TS#","",7,7,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_FILE1","",43,43,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_COL2","",49,49,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_OBJ#","",3,3,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","C_OBJ#","",2,2,"CLUSTER",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",5,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_CDEF3","",55,55,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","C_COBJ#","",29,29,"CLUSTER",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",5,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","CCOL$","",32,29,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_OBJ5","",40,40,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","PROXY_ROLE_DATA$","",25,25,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_CDEF1","",53,53,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","C_USER#","",10,10,"CLUSTER",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",5,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","C_FILE#_BLOCK#","",8,8,"CLUSTER",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",5,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","FET$","",12,6,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_CON2","",52,52,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_OBJ4","",39,39,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","CON$","",28,28,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_CDEF2","",54,54,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","ICOL$","",20,2,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_COL3","",50,50,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_CCOL1","",57,57,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","COL$","",21,2,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_ICOL1","",42,42,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","UET$","",13,8,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","PROXY_DATA$","",23,23,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","USER$","",22,10,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_PROXY_ROLE_DATA$_2","",27,27,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_OBJ2","",37,37,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","TAB$","",4,2,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_COBJ#","",30,30,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_USER#","",11,11,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","FILE$","",17,17,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","OBJ$","",18,18,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,15-OCT-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","TS$","",16,6,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_UNDO1","",34,34,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","BOOTSTRAP$","",59,59,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_COL1","",48,48,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_FILE2","",44,44,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_IND1","",41,41,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_USER2","",47,47,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_USER1","",46,46,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","SEG$","",14,8,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:25","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","OBJERROR$","",60,60,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:26","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","OBJAUTH$","",61,61,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:26","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_OBJAUTH1","",62,62,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:26","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_OBJAUTH2","",63,63,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:27","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","C_OBJ#_INTCOL#","",64,64,"CLUSTER",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:27","VALID","N","N","N",5,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_OBJ#_INTCOL#","",65,65,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:27","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","HISTGRM$","",66,64,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:27","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_H_OBJ#_COL#","",67,67,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:27","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","HIST_HEAD$","",68,68,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:27","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_HH_OBJ#_COL#","",69,69,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:27","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_HH_OBJ#_INTCOL#","",70,70,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:27","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","FIXED_OBJ$","",71,71,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:27","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_FIXED_OBJ$_OBJ#","",72,72,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:27","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","TAB_STATS$","",73,73,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:28","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_TAB_STATS$_OBJ#","",74,74,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:28","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","IND_STATS$","",75,75,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:28","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_IND_STATS$_OBJ#","",76,76,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:28","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","OBJECT_USAGE","",77,77,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:28","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_STATS_OBJ#","",78,78,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:28","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","PARTOBJ$","",79,79,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:28","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_PARTOBJ$","",80,80,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:28","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","DEFERRED_STG$","",81,81,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:28","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_DEFERRED_STG1","",82,82,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:28","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","DEPENDENCY$","",83,83,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:28","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","ACCESS$","",84,84,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:29","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_DEPENDENCY1","",85,85,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:29","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_DEPENDENCY2","",86,86,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:29","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_ACCESS1","",87,87,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:29","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","USERAUTH$","",88,88,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:29","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_USERAUTH1","",89,89,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:29","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","UGROUP$","",90,90,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:29","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_UGROUP1","",91,91,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:29","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_UGROUP2","",92,92,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:29","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","TSQ$","",93,10,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:29","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","SYN$","",94,94,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:29","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","VIEW$","",95,95,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:29","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","TYPED_VIEW$","",96,96,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:29","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","SUPEROBJ$","",97,97,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:29","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_SUPEROBJ1","",98,98,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:29","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_SUPEROBJ2","",99,99,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:29","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
"SYS","SEQ$","",100,100,"TABLE",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:29","VALID","N","N","N",1,"","METADATA LINK","","Y","N","USING_NLS_COMP","N","N",,,,
"SYS","I_VIEW1","",101,101,"INDEX",07-FEB-18,07-FEB-18,"2018-02-07:19:20:29","VALID","N","N","N",4,"","NONE","","Y","N","","N","N",,,,
 
100 ROWS selected. 
 
SQL> spool off
SQL> CREATE TABLE demo_load AS SELECT * FROM all_objects WHERE 1=2;
 
TABLE DEMO_LOAD created.
 
SQL> LOAD demo_load objects.csv
--Insert failed in batch rows  101  through  103 
--ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("HR"."DEMO_LOAD"."OWNER")
--Row 101 data follows:
INSERT INTO DEMO_LOAD(OWNER,OBJECT_NAME,SUBOBJECT_NAME,OBJECT_ID,DATA_OBJECT_ID,OBJECT_TYPE,CREATED,LAST_DDL_TIME,TIMESTAMP,STATUS,TEMPORARY,GENERATED,SECONDARY,NAMESPACE,EDITION_NAME,SHARING,EDITIONABLE,ORACLE_MAINTAINED,APPLICATION,DEFAULT_COLLATION,DUPLICATED,SHARDED,CREATED_APPID,CREATED_VSNID,MODIFIED_APPID,MODIFIED_VSNID)
VALUES ('','','',NULL,NULL,'',to_date(''),to_date(''),'','','','','',NULL,'','','','','','','','',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
--Row 102 data follows:
INSERT INTO DEMO_LOAD(OWNER,OBJECT_NAME,SUBOBJECT_NAME,OBJECT_ID,DATA_OBJECT_ID,OBJECT_TYPE,CREATED,LAST_DDL_TIME,TIMESTAMP,STATUS,TEMPORARY,GENERATED,SECONDARY,NAMESPACE,EDITION_NAME,SHARING,EDITIONABLE,ORACLE_MAINTAINED,APPLICATION,DEFAULT_COLLATION,DUPLICATED,SHARDED,CREATED_APPID,CREATED_VSNID,MODIFIED_APPID,MODIFIED_VSNID)
VALUES ('100 rows selected. ','','',NULL,NULL,'',to_date(''),to_date(''),'','','','','',NULL,'','','','','','','','',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
--Row 103 data follows:
INSERT INTO DEMO_LOAD(OWNER,OBJECT_NAME,SUBOBJECT_NAME,OBJECT_ID,DATA_OBJECT_ID,OBJECT_TYPE,CREATED,LAST_DDL_TIME,TIMESTAMP,STATUS,TEMPORARY,GENERATED,SECONDARY,NAMESPACE,EDITION_NAME,SHARING,EDITIONABLE,ORACLE_MAINTAINED,APPLICATION,DEFAULT_COLLATION,DUPLICATED,SHARDED,CREATED_APPID,CREATED_VSNID,MODIFIED_APPID,MODIFIED_VSNID)
VALUES ('','','',NULL,NULL,'',to_date(''),to_date(''),'','','','','',NULL,'','','','','','','','',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
--Number of rows processed: 103
--Number of rows in error: 3
1 - WARNING: LOAD processed WITH errors
SQL> commit;
```

The LOAD command is available from the SQL Worksheet in SQL Developer's GUI as well.

For more information see these two posts

- [using Load on an existing table with CSV](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2019/09/sqlcl-and-the-load-csv-command/)
- [using Load to create a new table on-the-fly with CSV](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2021/11/sqlcl-load-csv-create-new-tables-or-just-generate-the-ddl/)

*Disclaimer: I work for Oracle and I'm the product manager for SQL Developer and SQLcl.*

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, actually maybe I explained myself badly. My goal is to create a pl/sql PROCEDURE that can import a .csv file to a table within my schema. I don't want to use or install additional tools to do this action.

Comment: Why write code if you don't have to? Also, SQLcl is part of your database/client install, so nothing new to install. There are many PL/SQL solutions similar to what you're looking for out there, so I'm sure you'll be successful in that route. Note that your files will need to be in a database directory, on the server, for this to work, unless you want to reach out over the network using UTL/HTP packages.

Comment: I have this tried on, and I don't like the fact that the directory is on the Oracle server, I want it all to be on my machine, what can I do?

Comment: try exactly what i show - the data is read from the client, where sqlcl is running. Alternatively you can have it stream from the Oracle Object Store, if you're using the Oracle Cloud.

Comment: Ok what if instead I wanted to export a table in a csv present locally in my machine?

Comment: then 'set sqlformat csv...spool file.csv...select * from table....spool off - there's your file